# Intellisense for angular2

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

There are some problems with my Visual Studio 2015, actually with Intellisense. It doesn’t recognize angular syntax. For example if I try to write *ngFor, or *ngIf, or [style.margin.px] I am not getting any hints from Intellisense, but when I manually write the code and run it, everything works fine. I’ve tried to install AngularIntellisense from NGPM, nothing changed. I have all the latest updates for VS 2015. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use visual Studio code. It provides the Intellisense for many languages . It is actually  very good for angularjs development . You just need to install the extensions as per your need such as  Material design , boot strap, JShint, CSS, AngularJS etc.

You can download form here:  https://code.visualstudio.com/ 
 You can also user SUBLIME editor

Comment: It looks like that's the only solution for now. Thanks for your answer.