# Why ng-repeat is not working with table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-repeat not working with table,in the output only header part displayed? As i think the binding i did is perfectly fine, but something is there which i am missing? 
When i try to run in Stackoverflow ide it is working fine.

I am using ADOBE Brackets.whether its the error in brackets??
Please suggest the best IDE for angularjs ?
Can anyone help me out where i am doing wrong?

```js
var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);
var mycontroller=function($scope)
{
var employees=[
    {Name:'Sahil',dateOfBirth:new Date(),gender:"Male",salary: 400000},
    {Name:'Shaloni',dateOfBirth:new Date(),gender:"Female",salary: 100000},
    {Name:'Nitish',dateOfBirth:new Date(),gender:"Male",salary: 300000},
    {Name:'Diksha',dateOfBirth:new Date(),gender:"Female",salary: 600000},
    {Name:'Tarun',dateOfBirth:new Date(),gender:"Male",salary: 900000}
]
$scope.emp=employees;
};
myApp.controller('myController',mycontroller);
```

```html
<HTML ng-app="myApp">
<Head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="day4.js"></script>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
</Head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="myController">
<table>
<thead>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Date Of Birth</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Salary</th>
<th>Salary in Dollors</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="employee in emp">
    <td>{{employee.Name}}</td>    
    <td>{{employee.dateOfBirth}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Try using visual studio code or jetBrains.

Comment: Are you seeing any error in console or network tab? [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/zyw6kruq/)  it is working

Comment: its working fine. sublime Atom jetBrains there are many IDE

Comment: Works for me in chrome.

Comment: code is working in snippet window.. whats the error ?

Comment: 1 small issue which i can see is you have the th elements  not wrapped inside a tr element, not sure if this will fix but give it a try. if not fix, could you use this plunker to recreate your problem https://plnkr.co/edit/UpWeg8td29VV6ODb9AvI?p=preview

Comment: @user2181397 : No error in console window.

Comment: Not working for me in any browser .

Answer (score 0):

Please find your solution , https://plnkr.co/edit/hFIfPlTcP8VLVE72coth

And problem in your code is here :
  var mycontroller=function($scope)
and  myApp.controller('myController',mycontroller);

mycontroller variable is not getting called. put Alert(); in that block and see.

And for editor you can use  SUBLIME editor , Visual studio code, : [Intellisense for angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129998/intellisense-for-angular2/38130173#38130173)

```js
var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);
var mycontroller=function($scope)
{
var employees=[
    {Name:'Sahil',dateOfBirth:new Date(),gender:"Male",salary: 400000},
    {Name:'Shaloni',dateOfBirth:new Date(),gender:"Female",salary: 100000},
    {Name:'Nitish',dateOfBirth:new Date(),gender:"Male",salary: 300000},
    {Name:'Diksha',dateOfBirth:new Date(),gender:"Female",salary: 600000},
    {Name:'Tarun',dateOfBirth:new Date(),gender:"Male",salary: 900000}
]
$scope.emp=employees;
};
myApp.controller('myController',mycontroller);
```

```html
<HTML ng-app="myApp">
<Head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="day4.js"></script>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
</Head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="myController">
<table>
<thead>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Date Of Birth</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Salary</th>
<th>Salary in Dollors</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="employee in emp">
    <td>{{employee.Name}}</td>    
    <td>{{employee.dateOfBirth}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
</body>
</HTML>
```